# How to export multiple MXDs to PNG without using VBA?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, mxd, png

Okay, so I can feel that I am so close to solving this issue with the help of Jason (below) but I have modified to use as a script.  The GetParameterAsText returns the following error when trying to execute:

> : [Error 3] The system cannot find the
>   path specified:
>   u"'C:\Users\bob\Documents\folder\file.mxd';'C:\Users\folder\Documents\Folder\file.mxd';'C:\Users\folder\Documents\folder\file.mxd'\*.*"

Anyone know what is wrong with my code to keep getting this error?

```
    import arcpy, os, string

    #Read input/output folder path from script tool
    folderPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    outPNGfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

    for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
        fullpath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
            basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
            if extension.lower() == ".mxd":
                mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
                arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, basename + '.png')
```

Comment: What is "mapping.PNGDcoumentCreate(outPNGpath)? This isn't a real mapping function. You don't need this line. You can download Pyscripter (free) and learn to debug your script.

Comment: I was trying to modify an existing script that batch converts multiple map documents into a single PDF.  I am new to all of this but couldn't find a simple solution to batch export multiple mxds into pngs thru model builder so I naturally migrated to python.  I will look into pyscripter.  Thank you.

Comment: The ESRI online help has nice examples on how to use various  arcpy.mapping functions & classes. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00qp0000000v000000.htm

Comment: What are you passing as your parameters? It should just be a single directory path.

Comment: Sir, you are a genius.  I had my parameters set to ArcMap Document instead of top level folder.  That worked flawlessly.  On another note, is it possible to do it by selected map project

Comment: @Tom - can you please make that an answer.

Answer (score 3):

From Jeff Moulds (ESRI) originally for pdf export here's some python you can customize.  It works on all mxds in a folder so you could adjust that or perhaps copy the projects into one temporarily for exporting.  I added paragraph spaces after the first 3 lines to make the text properly indent in the box below, not being smart enough to do that any other way.

```
import arcpy, os
folderPath = r"C:\Project"
for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
    fullpath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
        if extension.lower() == ".mxd":
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, basename + '.png')
```